# Can I update field to same value for every row in a list?

Tags: list, update

I want to update a field to the same value for every row in a list all at once.

For example:

```
List<Opportunity> osl: [SELECT Id, CloseDate from Opportunity WHERE CloseDate !=: today;
osl.CloseDate = today;
update osl;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: dont forget to accept an answer, if either of the bellow helped.

Answer (score 3):

There's a new feature that's in pilot, which I believe is called "update by example", which was announced at Dreamforce. Basically it behaves like the SQL "update" statement, where you fire off an update based on a query and a template. This is in pilot, so you'll want to contact salesforce.com to see if you can get in on it.

Similarly, you can theoretically use a StandardSetController to do this:

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController c = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate <> TODAY]);
c.getRecord().put('CloseDate', System.today());
c.setSelected(c.getRecords());
c.save();
```

But in practice it does not seem to work.

Other than that, looping is the only guaranteed way to make this work if you don't have the update by example API, and until/unless they fix StandardSetController.

Comment: geez -- you'd think this would work as it can be done via the UI `The StandardSetController class also contains a prototype object. This is a single sObject contained within the Visualforce StandardSetController class. If the prototype object's fields are set, those values are used during the save action, meaning that the values are applied to every record in the set controller's collection. This is useful for writing pages that perform mass updates (applying identical changes to fields within a collection of objects).`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can iterate through the list of opportunities and set the same field value for each of them.

```
List<Opportunity> osl = [SELECT Id, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate != :System.Today()];
for(Opportunity opp : osl) {
    opp.CloseDate = System.Today();
}
update osl;
```

Comment: I mean without looping through

Comment: @AverageJoeVBA, Salesforce does not allow to mass update based on DML statement like oracle- plsql. So, each records to be assigned and perform update on list

Comment: In Salesforce the pattern is as written above, query, then iterate over the results and modify any fields and then perform the update. You cannot execute an `UPDATE CloseDate = Today() WHERE CloseDate != Today()` operation like you can in SQL.

Comment: @SantanuBoral There's a pilot for that, actually.

Comment: @sfdcfox, nice to know.